# How to solve system of nonlinear equations with parameters in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations in Python. The equations have the form:

(1) x^2 + y^2 = a

(2)(x-b)^2 + y^2 = c

where x and y are the variables and a,b,c are parameters. I would like to have a function which i can pass the parameters a,b,c to and it returns me the values for x and y. How can I do that ?

What i currently have is

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def equation(var, *data):
    a,b,c = data 
    x,y = var
    eq1 = x**2 + y**2 - a**2
    eq2 = (x - b)**2 + y**2 - c**2
    return [eq1, eq2]

x,y = fsolve(equation, args=data)
```

But this does not quite work. Can someone help?

Comment: "does not quite work" - what does that mean?  Something different from plain "not work" or "there's an error"?  We like to see actual error messages - with full traceback.

Comment: It's the intersection of two circles, so you might have 0, 1 or 2 solutions depending on a, b and c. It's probably easier to solve it as a geometry problem...

Comment: Your code, a posted, gives a "NameError: name 'data' is not defined"

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just missing the initialized values

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def equation(var, *data):
    a,b,c = data 
    x,y = var
    eq1 = x**2 + y**2 - a**2
    eq2 = (x - b)**2 + y**2 - c**2
   return [eq1, eq2]

x,y = fsolve(equation,[1,1], args=(1,1,1))
print(x,y)
```

Comment: Note that this gives only one of the 2 solutions with these values of a, b, and c, and that it will output some totally invalid solution in other cases. For example, there is no solution with a=1, b=1, c=4, but this will output `-2.496825048521279 -0.004737261091547693` with a warning `RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.` As commented under the question, it's probably better to consider it as a geometry problem (the intersection of 2 circles).

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from geometrical interpretation of Thierry Lathuille, there is maybe no real need to use a nonlinear solver.

First, Eq. (1) requires y^2=a^2-x^2 and thus (x-b)^2+a^2-x^2=c^2 according to Eq. (2). The latter equality simplifies to b^2-2bx+a^2=c^2 with xSol=(a^2+b^2-c^2)/(2b) as the possible solution for x (the symmetry suggest that there'll be only one solution for x). With this solution for x, we can check the sign of a^2-xSol^2. If negative, then there is no solution. If non-negative, then the solutions are (xSol,+ySol) and (xSol,-ySol) with ySol=np.sqrt(a^2-xSol^2).

Based on some testing with the code below, the solution above seems to work (but correct me if I'm wrong).

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

abc = (1,1,4)

# Nonlinear optimizer
def equation(var, *data):
    a,b,c = data
    x,y = var
    eq1 = x**2 + y**2 - a**2
    eq2 = (x - b)**2 + y**2 - c**2
    return [eq1, eq2]

x,y = fsolve(equation,[1,1], args=abc)
print(x,y)

# Geometric solution
a = abc[0]; b = abc[1]; c = abc[2]
xSol = (a**2+b**2-c**2)/(2*b)
if a**2-xSol**2<0:
    print("No solution")
else:
    ySol = np.sqrt(a**2-xSol**2)
    print(xSol,ySol)
    print(xSol,-ySol)
```

Comment: But this is math, not engineering :)